# MPCA (Multi Linear Priciple Componont Analysis) code to find the pattern of the gabor filtered image

Tags: matlab, pca

Hi i want to develop the matlab code for the gabor filterd images , to find the pattern from these images, which can be further used to classify the test face in different class for age estimation.

i have prodused the gabor filtered image , now i want to write the matlab code for Multilinear Princiuple Compononty Analysis, which is simmilar to PCA , but operates in multimode.(2 mode for 100*1,100*1 for 100*100 images )

please give me a idea to write the code.